# Из списка стран открыть список соответствующих городов

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Как реализовать следующее в `UITableView`
В первом окне дожен быть список стран, при клике на любую  страну должно открываться список соответствующих этой стране городов. Какую модель использовать `NSArray`  или `NSDictionary` для Страна-Города, что должно быть реализовано в

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

и что должно передаваться в

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: ууу вам бы матчасть подучить...

Comment: Ключ - страна, значение - массив городов. В чем проблема то, непонятно...??

Comment: а в первой таблице тогда как отображать страну?

Comment: Есть словарь, в котором ключ - это страна, значение - города.
Первую заполняете ключами, вторую значениями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут нагуглил [видос](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lskuwpMT2g)

Вот тут [тутор](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/)

[Сам запрос может что еще найдете](https://www.google.ru/search?q=UItableView+examples&oq=UItableView+examples&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4251j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1#newwindow=1&q=UItableView+examples+pushing&qscrl=1)

**UPD**

Ааа ну это как удобно, вот мы в своем проекте имели простую таблицу с иерархическими индексами: т.е.

|индекс города/области/страны | индекс родительского элемента | Название города |

ну как то-так примерно. Потом получали все индексы из базы родительский индекс, которых равен 0 т.е. рутовые объекты ( у нас это были страны)
данный список грузим в TableView по делегату

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

получаем индекс нажатой ячейки, ну и берем по индексу из массива сосоответствующую модель. Теперь у нас есть индекс рутового объекта. 
вызываем новый экземляр данного контроллера и передаем в конструктор индекс рутового объекта:

```
CityViewController *cityViewController = [[CityViewController alloc]initWithRootIndex:13];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cityViewController animated:YES];
```

Ну и по аналогии рекурсивно пока не дойдете до улицы

Comment: это я могу делать, не все так печально :) проблема в том что я не совсем понимаю как во втором окне отобразить UITableView с результатами городов из выбранной ячейки страны. Т.е. как мне связать страны и города друг с другом?

Comment: UPDATE....